# add another element to a python iterator

Tags: python, dictionary

I get an object *oData* (classed as an iterable object) in python via some blackbox function:

```
oData = someFunction()
```

When I do this:

```
HttpResponse( oData )
```

I get:

```
{'A':0.0, 'B':1.0, 'C':1.0 }
```

I can't do

```
HttpResponse( type(oData) )
```

I just get a 500 server error. Why is this not just a string? How do I get this to output the info I need? Anyway that is secondary.

**Ultimately what I want to do is have oData as a dictionary object so I can add one element to it like so:**

```
{ 'A':0.0, 'B':1.0, 'C':1.0, 'New':'myValue' }
```

**How do I do that?**

----- Edit: just to clarify some things... (and also omitted some irrelevant info above)

oData is indeed an immutable object with a definition for an `__iter__()` method.
The answer I seek would probably involve cloning its data somehow so that I can append to it.
I've tried this with no luck

```
oCopy = ( i for i in oData )
```

In PHP I would simply gather the key-value pairs and store them into an associative array.

Comment: If you don't understand how the language works, learn. Don't blame the language.

Comment: What do `oData`, `type(oData)` and `list(oData)` look like?

Comment: @ Blender, I can't print them directly. It is running inside a Django web server. But Print and HttpResponse ought to have the same behaviour, imo.

Comment: While python `list` and `dict` objects have a shorthand that's close to JSON, they are not truly JSON. JSON doesn't support single quoted property names, or single quoted strings, you'll still have to use the json library to convert a dict/list into a proper json result.

Comment: I don't work with Django, but you should be able to get those values somehow: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: @Octopus If you wanted to inspect the result of `type(oData)` you need to either use the `str(...)` method to get a string representation of the object, or access the `.__name__` property to get the type name.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `type(oData)`, you get - unsurprisingly - a [`type`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) object, which is not iterable (what would that even mean?).

You want a string representation of that object. Use [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str) for that:

```
HttpResponse( str(type(oData)) )
```

will get you the name of the type, and

```
oData['New'] = 'myValue'
HttpResponse( str(oData) )
```

will return something like

```
{ 'A':0.0, 'B':1.0, 'C':1.0, 'New':'myValue' }
```

Comment: str(type(oData)) gave me some info i wanted. my question though, is how to i transform the iterable oData at the beginning to the one at the end?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean with beginning and end? If `oData` is not a `dict`, you must either consult its documentation on how to assign values, or call `dict(oData)` to create a dict from `oData`s contents.

Comment: oData is actually a set of data as retrieved from a database. in this case it is a single row with three columns. when I go dict(oData) I get: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required", but yes, all i want to do isconvert it to a  dictionary so i can append to it as i would to a dictionary.

Comment: @Octopus Well, can you show us the code or documentation to whatever is generating that set? `dict` supports a set of tuples, but it looks like that class is something else.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment on another answer, I'm betting `oData` is a list of [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s and that `HttpResponse` is doing some kind of magic to convert it to the result you see. Observe this demonstration, which gives the same error you mentioned:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> X = namedtuple('X', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> x = X(1,2,3)
>>> dict([x])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

That would explain why you can't modify it. Tuples, named or any other kind, are immutable.

The simplest way I can think of to convert it to a `dict` is to make use of [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)

```
>>> dict(vars(x))
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Since `someFunction` returns an iterable, you'll need to iterate over each element to turn all rows into `dict`s:

```
oDataDicts = [dict(vars(r)) for r in oData]
```

You could try to extract the first element instead if you expect 1, but that would mean more code handling the case when there's not 1.

Normally, calling `vars` returns a `dict`, but for `namedtuple`, it seems to return an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). If the `OrderedDict` doesn't bother you, you can leave off the extra call to `dict`.

Additionally, I would highly recommend you be a bit more explicit about the output you want to include in your response. Relying on `HttpResponse`'s behavior will probably make it more difficult to remember what the code is supposed to do later on. If you want to send a JSON response, explicitly converting it to JSON would be a good idea.

Comment: @Octopus My answer has undergone several revisions. Think I figured out your problem, but I wanted to make sure you got notified in case you looked at an older version.

Comment: @jpmc, I think the magic is not in the HttpResponse method but in the oData object's implementation of an __iter__ function. I have editted the answer somewhat to hopefully make my situation more understandable. I will try dict(vars(oData)) tomorrow from work. It might be the answer I am after.

Comment: That could be the case, but I think it's more likely that the magic is in the definition of the objects contained in the iterable.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. If they're named tuples, they can't have that kind of logic.